# Given a matrix of a linear transformation in an unknown basis, can we recover the linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to answer this and elaborated the following artificial problem for that matter:

Suppose we have been given a transformation $T(x,x+y)$, in the basis $B=\{(1,1),(0,1)\}$ we have $T(1,1)=(1,2)$ and $T(0,1)=(0,1)$. With this, we can form the matrix of $T$ in the basis $B$, now forget the basis we had: Can we (with only this matrix) recover $T$? Perhaps this is something very stupid but I've been trying to answer this and I tried a lot of stuff but couldn't answer it.

Comment: In short, except for simple cases like the zero matrix or a multiple of the identity, no.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case we can form the matrix that represents $\textsf T$ with respect to the basis $B$ and the standard basis $\gamma =\{ (1,0),(0,1) \}$, like this :
$$[\textsf T]_B^{\gamma} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Now, let $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, and we put it as a linear combination of the elements of $ B $ :
$$(x,y) = x(1,1)+(-x+y)(0,1)$$
then, their coordinate vector is given by
$$[(x,y)]_B= \begin{pmatrix} x \\ -x+y \end{pmatrix}$$
and the most important part is that
$$[\textsf{T}(x,y)]_\gamma = [\textsf T]_B^{\gamma} [(x,y)]_B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ -x+y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ x+y \end{pmatrix}$$
in other words
$$\textsf{T}(x,y) = x(1,0)+(x+y)(0,1)=(x,x+y)$$
In general, always keep in mind that
$$[\textsf{T}(u)]_\gamma = [\textsf T]_\beta^\gamma [u]_\beta$$
If we forget the initial basis $B$, then the answer is no. But given any matrix $ A\in \textsf{M}_{m\times n}(F)$ we can define the *left multiplication transformation* $\textsf{L}_A : F^n\to F^m$ by $$\textsf{L}_A(x)=Ax$$

Comment: The OP writes “now forget the basis we had.” You don’t have those basis vectors with which to form the linear combination in your very first step.

Comment: I see, then the answer is no.  Given any matrix, many different transformations could be associated depending on the choice of basis. But that could be fixed as follows, given $ A\in \textsf{M}_{m\times n}(F)$ let's define the linear map $\textsf{L}_A : F^n\to F^m$ by $$\textsf{L}_A(x)=Ax$$

Comment: You’re “fixing” things in that comment by in effect assuming a particular basis in which to interpret $A$. That doesn’t solve the problem at hand, which comes down to identifying a correct basis for $A$.